# Why didn’t Picard's traumatic experiences break him?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

Picard was tortured by Cardassians (pretty efficiently, as we saw in the end), assimilated (a trauma which affected him throughout his life), relived a whole (fake) life where he had a wife and children whom he "lost" when he returned to reality (he showed in that episode and later ones that he cared), he "died" and saw an alternate version of himself who didn't take risks... and much more.

I can only ask myself, how come he is still the captain after all that trauma? How come he didn't get PTSD or a similar condition? Starfleet did send him away after the Borg incurred into Sector 001 for the second time just to be safe.

How come this man keeps his sanity after all those traumatic events?

Comment: I'm not sure there's going to be a good answer to this. Perhaps he's just unusually resilient. There are real-world survivors of torture who went on to lead successful lives.

Comment: he does carry a full time counselor around with him, as well as Troi (da da bum #Guinan)

Comment: Medicinal marijuana.

Comment: dancing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krEGw4iuSJM

Comment: We do see after the Borg incident that Picard was pretty shook up about being assimilated and those related experiences.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is answer worthy, but in Picard's time medical technology is ludicrously advanced. If [McCoy could cure a plague, on his own, without access to a computer, in a matter of days, *a century earlier*](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Miri_(episode)), I imagine psychological trauma is not exceptionally difficult to mitigate in the 24th century. Remember, the brain is an organ too.

Comment: Civan, a few years ago, I watched a freshman cadet pass four upper classmen on the last hill of the forty kilometre run on Danula Two. Damnedest thing I ever saw. The only freshman to ever win the Academy marathon. I made it my business to get to know that young fellow. I got to know him very, very well, and I'll tell you something: I never met anyone with more drive, determination, or more courage than Jean-Luc Picard. There is no way in hell that he would let a few traumatic experiences damage his sanity. I want that clear.

Comment: Just to broaden the question, the man is a distinguished diplomat and peace maker. This role requires tremendous concentration and clarity. Yet again, Starfleet sends this man as first time negotiator to new worlds, when in reality if he sees any reminder to his Borg experience he might lose his cool.

Comment: PTSD has been cured in the 24th century.

Comment: Paul D. Waite - the original quote didn't make much sense.  In the 21st century most freshman cadets should be as big and strong as they will ever be.  There is no reason to expect much change in speed or endurance between an 18-year-old 24th century cadet and a 22-year old one - unless the Academy artificially and slowly enhances cadet fitness over a period of years.  "The race goeth not to the strong" according to Pliny the Elder's account of ten year old boy who ran something like 80 miles in a day.  About one quarter of the winners of that race should have been freshman cadets.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, the same reason only some military personnel develop PTSD or similar conditions

Psychiatry is not an exact science a man may be able to bounce back from extreme physical torture with no lasting mental effects but the same man would spend the rest of his life in a padded room if you locked him in a closet full of cockroaches for an hour

There is no way to tell what will actually traumatize someone

Comment: That's a great answer...but I don't buy it. The real reason is that TNG was still being written under "reset button" rules for the most part.

Comment: In all honesty the things a lot of fictional people are subjected to over the course of their show or movie probably would cause significant psychological damage to most real people but we want to see them do things not sit in a padded room rocking back and forth

Answer (score -3):

Or possibly most episodes happen in alternate universes to all the other episodes and it is very rare for any episode except for important arc episodes to be sequels to other episodes.  So we can hope that Picard did not experience "The Best of Both Worlds",  "Chain of Command", "The Inner Light", and "Tapestry" in the same  universe.  It is possible that in most alternate universes Picard and the Federaton survived "The Best of Both Worlds", but Picard took a lot longer to recover than in "Family" and in many of them he may never haver recovered.

I remember a *Rocky and His Friends* episode where a seed of a man-eating plant entered the submarine that took Boris, Natasha, and Fearless Leader back to Pottsylvania.  When the sub arrived, the man-eating plant emerged, but Boris and Natasha were seen in many later episdoes. So if  Rocky and His Friends’ stories happen in many different alternate universes it can explain how Boris and Natasha were alive in many stories after supposedly being eaten.

Thus the Star Trek characters could be executed, or fired, or imprisoned, or go insane, etc. after many episodes, but we don't see those effects because all the other episodes are in alternate universes.

Comment: Interesting theory. Any clues given to that effect?

Comment: Zabeus - That theory is based on observations of long TV series in general and Star Trek in particular.  Several episodes like "Where no One has Gone Before", "Q Who?" , "The Price", and in other series indicate that maximum warp speed for long trips should not be faster than the official warp factor formula.  Adding up the minimum total distance traveled may show, for example, that they traveled much farther than would be possible if all the episodes happened in the same alternate universe.